# Using config file with Paypal SDK throws PayPalInvalidCredentialException

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

<sup>This was originally a support ticket that ended up being my [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). I'm posting it to stack overflow to help anyone that comes behind me. Hopefully, it'll save you some time.</sup>

#### Required Information

- PHP Version: 5.3
- PayPal-PHP-SDK Version: 1.11
- Debug ID(s): ?

#### Issue Description

Using the instructions at: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/File-based-Configurations does not seem to work. I'm getting the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PayPal\Exception\PayPalInvalidCredentialException' with message 'Credential not found for  default user. Please make sure your configuration/APIContext has credential information
```

The above article links to [sample code](https://gist.github.com/jaypatel512/94e626b684f6fefa5078) that doesn't match the code in the article. Furthermore, it seems to reference a nonexistent `$apiContext`.

The official [samples](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/tree/master/sample) contain an [sdk_config.ini](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/sdk_config.ini), but it doesn't seem to be used anywhere.

Other (older) [sources](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-php/wiki/Configuring-the-SDK#api-credentials) prefer to use the "Classic TEST API Credentials." I'd prefer to use the id and secret as this seems to be a better solution if only it would work.

#### Files

*(Please ignore the bad practices. This is an experiment.)*

test.php

```
require_once  '../../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once './class/PaymentManager.php';
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

print_r("\n\n");

$payment = new PaymentManager();
$payment->test();

print_r("\n\n");
```

PaymentManager.php

```
if(!defined("PP_CONFIG_PATH")) {
    define("PP_CONFIG_PATH", 'config/paypal.ini');
}

class PaymentManager {


    public function test(){
        echo $this->saveCC("visa", "4417119669820331", "012", "11", "2019", "Joe", "Shopper");
    }


    private function saveCC($type, $number, $ccv, $month, $year, $firstName, $lastName){
        error_log(file_get_contents('config/paypal.ini'));
        $creditCard = new \PayPal\Api\CreditCard();
        $creditCard->setType($type)
            ->setNumber($number)
            ->setExpireMonth($month)
            ->setExpireYear($year)
            ->setCvv2($ccv)
            ->setFirstName($firstName)
            ->setLastName($lastName);

        try {
            $creditCard->create();
        }
        catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
            error_log("Exception while saving CC: ".$ex->getData());
        }

        return $creditCard;
    }


}
```

paypal.ini

```
; Modified from: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/sdk_config.ini

;## This is an example configuration file for the SDK.
;## This is an example configuration file for the SDK.
;## The sample scripts configure the SDK dynamically
;## but you can choose to go for file based configuration
;## in simpler apps (See bootstrap.php for more).
[Account]
acct1.ClientId = [REDACTED]
acct1.ClientSecret = [REDACTED]

;Connection Information
[Http]
; Add Curl Constants to be configured
; The settings provided in configurations would override defaults
; if provided in configurations
http.CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT = 30

; Adding HTTP Headers to each request sent to PayPal APIs
;http.headers.PayPal-Partner-Attribution-Id = 123123123

;http.Proxy=http://[username:password]@hostname[:port]

;Service Configuration
[Service]
; can be set to sandbox / live
mode = sandbox

;Logging Information
[Log]
; For custom logging implementation, you can set the
; logging factory provider class here.
; The class should be implementing \PayPal\Log\PayPalLogFactory.
; If this is not set, it will default to \PayPal\Log\PayPalDefaultLogFactory.
;log.AdapterFactory=\PayPal\Log\PayPalDefaultLogFactory

; Settings for PayPalDefaultLogFactory
log.LogEnabled=true

; When using a relative path, the log file is created
; relative to the .php file that is the entry point
; for this request. You can also provide an absolute
; path here
; Settings for PayPalDefaultLogFactory
log.FileName=config/PayPal.log

; Logging level can be one of any provided at \Psr\Log\LogLevel
; Logging is most verbose in the 'DEBUG' level and
; decreases as you proceed towards ERROR
; DEBUG level is disabled for live, to not log sensitive information.
; If the level is set to DEBUG, it will be reduced to INFO automatically
log.LogLevel=INFO

;Caching Configuration
[cache]
; If Cache is enabled, it stores the access token retrieved from ClientId and Secret from the
; server into a file provided by the cache.FileName option or by using
; the constant $CACHE_PATH value in PayPal/Cache/AuthorizationCache if the option is omitted/empty.
; If the value is set to 'true', it would try to create a file and store the information.
; For any other value, it would disable it
; Please note, this is a very good performance improvement, and we would encourage you to
; set this up properly to reduce the number of calls, to almost 50% on normal use cases
; PLEASE NOTE: You may need to provide proper write permissions to /var directory under PayPal-PHP-SDK on
; your hosting server or whichever custom directory you choose
cache.enabled=true
; When using a relative path, the cache file is created
; relative to the .php file that is the entry point
; for this request. You can also provide an absolute
; path here
cache.FileName=config/auth.cache
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

- `PP_CONFIG_PATH` should be the *path* to the .ini file, without the filename.

  ```
  if(!defined("PP_CONFIG_PATH")) {
      define("PP_CONFIG_PATH", 'config/');
  }
  ```
- The .ini file itself should be named `sdk_config.ini`. There may be a way to change the filename, but this is what the sdk looks for by default. I'm certainly interested if someone knows how to change it, but this is not a show stopper.